# Music with JavaFX

Tags: java, audio, javafx

I have a sound file involved in my JavaFX program, and I'm trying to abbreviate the URI for it so that it's easier for my program to run when sharing it with others.

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(new Media("file:///Users/Home/Desktop/tech/FX/explosion.mp3"));
```

One of the many abbreviations I've tried is this:

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(new Media("./explosion.mp3"));
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: uri.getScheme() == null! uri == './explosion.mp3'
```

The absolute URI works fine, (as shown in the first block) but any attempt at relativising it works in no fashion whatsoever. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add the project structure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor for Media requires a URL, so you'd need something starting with http:// or file://

```
Media m = new Media(Paths.get("test.mp3").toUri().toString());
new MediaPlayer(m).play();
```

Found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/media-tutorial/simpleplayer.htm